# Blender Texture Maps to Unity Translation

Tags: texturing

Blender has these options for baking texture maps:
Combination
Ambient Occlusion
Shadow
Normal
UV
Roughness
Emit
Environment
Diffuse
Glossy
Transmission
Subsurface


Unity has these options under Material for texture maps:
Albedo
Metallic
Normal
Height
Occlusion
Emission
Detail Mask


Would someone clear up the confusion for me?
(Unity = Blender)
Albedo = Diffuse
Metallic = ?????
Normal = Normal
Height = ?????
Occlusion = Ambient Occlusion (If I create these for my assets, does that mean less time baking light in Unity?)
Emission = ?????
Detail Mask = ?????


Thanks for your help with this. I'm having a hard time finding any reference. I might not be searching the correct key terms.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can help with some of these.  the Metallic shader is a mask between what you want to be metal and what you don't.  Height map is the same as a bump map, Emission acts like the Metallic, except seperating emission instead of metal.

I hope this is useful.

Comment: Thanks for the info. "Bump" isn't an option in Blender for baking. Does Bump correspond to Shadow, or Roughness ?

Comment: A bump map acts similar to a normal map, but a bump map can be used to alter the geometry of the mesh.  For instance, if you want **major** bump, like bump that would turn a plane into a landscape, you would subidvide the mesh a ton, and then you would add the bump map with a displacement modifier.  (bump maps can also be used for materials like a normal map., I think that normal maps are supposed to  have more detail.)